# How to map detailed text to a unigram or a bigram

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, cluster-analysis, gensim, topic-modeling

I am trying to figure out solution for requirement where in I am required to map long text to unigrams or bigrams. 
For example
"Ability to motivate and manage team. You should be able to track the progress of the team and intervene to improve the progress". This long text should be mapped to "Team management". Basically I am trying to figure out communication/analytical skills from the long text seen in document like Job descriptions. I am struggling to figure out a solution for this. I do not want to hard code as the long text keep changing. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is there a preset list of categories (skills) like "team management"? Can a text be assigned to more than one category?

Comment: yes there is a pre-set list. Yes, the long text can belong to more than one category

Comment: OK, then this is a "multi-label text classification" problem - that's the kind of docs/tutorial/example you'll need to follow. You have texts. Then you have a set list of classes those texts should be classified into. (Ignore the fact that they're 'unigrams' or 'bigrams' - they're just opaque labels, which might as well just be ID numbers, as far as any classifier is concerned.) With enough labeled texts – examples of which labels **should** apply to a text – you can try many different classifier options. But crucially: seek online info about "multi-label text classification".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a multi-class multi-label classification problem. There is a lexical way of solving this problem. The article [here](https://www.listendata.com/2018/05/sentiment-analysis-using-python.html) will help you in solving the problem. One could skip the sentiment analysis part as the focus of this question is topic mapping.

Comment: Thanks for the article, the taxonomy part looks interesting. I am trying it out.